# Excel IF formula to validate another formula

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I want to run below formula on all cells, where current value is  zero.

Formula on `C3`

```
=SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)
```

I have tried to put this in another IF statement to validate the cell value first and if that matches condition execute above formula

```
=IF(C3=0,SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2))
```

But here I am getting circular reference warning, because the second formula is depends upon same cell value. Is there any other way I can do it ?. mean running the formula if the value is equal to zero  on specific cell

Comment: Write a macro to put the formula only in blank cells or cells with a currently-zero value?  Any formula-based approach will, as you observe, raise a circular reference warning.

Comment: @acr: again, you are coming up with the almost same problem!! every time trying to find a work about! this is not going to finish at all! what you need to do to avoid ALL THIS, is to increment your raw data sheet, and not delete it every time you update it! You should keep it there and increment it each time updating it! This is the only solution to all your threads during the past few weeks.

Comment: Editing raw data sheet will not practcally possible due to some other restrictions. I able to complete what I am looking for using modified array formula which you have provided on other thread, but only problem I am facing is if I have more than 100 cell to calculate, the system utilization going high and each time system crashes. So I am trying to implement the same using a different method. Thanks for all your help..

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference the cell you are working in without creating a circular reference.  I usually just add an intermediate column to avoid this.  If you want it all in one cell for some reason:

```
=IF(SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)) = 0, "Sums are zero", SUMIFS(raw!$D:$D,raw!$A:$A,$A3,raw!$C:$C,C$2)))
```

Its probably takes twice as long to compute, is ugly, and you gotta keep both formulas the identical if you ever edit it, but it does fit in one cell.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all one worksheet, or multiple? I think the below would work, but can't know without the workbook.

=SUMPRODUCT((C3=0) * (raw!$A:$A = A3) * (raw!$C:$C = C2) * (raw!$D:$D))